# 2 Dimensional array initializer list exception

Tags: c++, arrays, initializer-list

[Exeption][image: 1]

Hello guys,
I'm trying to make an initializer_list constructor for 2D array.
Any Help, please?
.......................

```
    Matrix(int row,int col,const std::initializer_list<double>& list)
{
    rows = row;
    cols = col;
    std::initializer_list<double>::iterator it; 
    arr = new double* [rows];
    /*double* ptr = arr[k];*/
    int n = 0;
    for (it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); ++it)
    {
        int k = 0;
        if (n == cols)
        {
            k++;
            n = 0;
        }
        n++;
        arr[k][n] = *it;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please insert your code as text in the post, not as an image.

Comment: Hint: You allocated memory for `arr`, but were did you allocate memory for `arr[k]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not allocate enough memory. Also note that you probably do not want to reset `k` in every iteration and there are ranged-based loops if you want to do something on the entire container:

```
//correct allocation
int n = 0;
int k = 0;
for (auto const& number : list) {
  arr[k][n] = number;
  n++;
  if (n == col) {
    n = 0;
    ++k;
  }
}
```

There is also no need to declare variables before you need them. With iterators use `for(auto it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); ++it)`.
Also there is no need for temporary variables when they are function parameters and `row` and `col` do not have a type.